# Dynamically load external css resources model side

Tags: css, aurelia

I need to dynamically load external css resource to change font family of the page.

In my SPA the user chooses the font family he prefers for the UI. So he copy/paste the font family from https://fonts.google.com into an input tag and I need to change accordingly the page font-family property.

In order to do this, I need to load the external resource of the font such as `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<FONTFAMILYNAME>" rel="stylesheet">` and then change the css assigning `font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;` to the page, that is not a problem using css binding.

How can I do this from the model side?

**UPDATE**

The app is developed with Aurelia js framework, so I mean the Aurelia model, but (still in client-side)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "model side". Are you talking about doing this from a server instead of the client? Your question is kinda unclear.

Comment: @Geo1088 I updated the question, it should be clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope It is what you expected**

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let inpt = document.getElementById("inpt");
let fontsLink = document.getElementById("fontsLink");
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let font = inpt.value;
    font = font.trim();
    font = font.replace(/ /g, '+');
    let link = `
        https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${font}
    `
    fontsLink.href = link;
    document.querySelector('body').style.fontFamily = `${inpt.value}`;
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.25%;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World From Gaurav</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" id="fontsLink">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="demo" contenteditable="true">Change Text</h1>
    <input id="inpt" type="" placeholder="Type Font Name">
    <button id="btn">Load</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a really good hint but it isn't using the Aurelia framework. Thanks by the way.

Comment: The solution actually works like a charm and it needs only some consideration to be used with Aurelia application like adding a _fake_ link tag (called fontsLink in the answer) into the index.ejs file. it's not the best because of this. thanks @guarav